# Actionscript reparenting Canvas equivalent

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, html, canvas

I've been trying to teach myself some game physics and a book called Foundation ActionScript 3 was recommended.  I reckoned that the math principles would apply to other technologies too especially html5 canvas.  So in my curiosity I started converting ActionScript to JavaScript making some mental comparison in the process.  So far the principles and syntax has been very similar to my eyes but then I came upon this concept called "Reparenting".  I have the following code in ActionScript:

```
        parent1 = new Sprite();
        addChild(parent1);
        parent1.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
        parent1.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
        parent1.x = 60;
        parent1.y = 60;

        parent2 = new Sprite();
        addChild(parent2);
        parent2.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
        parent2.graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
        parent2.x = 170;
        parent2.y = 60;

        ball = new Sprite();
        parent1.addChild(ball);
        ball.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        ball.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
        ball.graphics.endFill();
        ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBallClick);

private function onBallClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (parent1.contains(ball)) {
                parent2.addChild(ball);
            }else if (parent2.contains(ball)) {
                parent1.addChild(ball);
            }

        }
```

So every time the ball is clicked it transfers to the other rectangle, becoming that rectangle "child".  Now I am wondering if JavaScript has a similar concept that allows me to gain similar effect with as minimal effort as ActionScript reparenting.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at in another way. Each parent is an 'origin' position which means it an area you position other items (children) in relation to.

You do not need anything fancy to fake this behavior.

```
function parent(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.addChild = function(child) {
        child.parent = this;
    }
}

function child(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.parent = 0;
    this.getXPos = function() {
        if(parent != 0)
            return this.x + parent.x;
        else
            return this.x;
    }

    this.getYPos = function() {
        if(parent != 0)
            return this.y + parent.y;
        else
            return this.y;
    }
}


daddy = new parent(60, 60);
mommy = new parent(60, 170);
sonny = new child(0, 0);
//add mouse click condition//
if(sonny.parent != daddy) daddy.addChild(sonny);
else mommy.addChild(sonny);
```

This should get you started(I haven't touched JS in awhile and did not check the syntax).
I would recommend sticking to making a game(in one language) unless the purpose is learning.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not that simple... think of canvas as a BitmapData rather than a MovieClip... if you draw something and you want to move it, you first have to erase it and draw it again in the next position... There are no containers or any of the fancy display list stuff in canvas.
You can, however, build your own display list like structure, or you can use a library like [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS).
Another alternative is to use the DOM, which for some situations might be better than working with a canvas element (although for game development it's probably not the way to go). In this case, you can use DOM elements as containers, so reparenting becomes quite trivial:

```
var parent1 = document.getElementById('parent1');
var parent2 = document.getElementById('parent2');
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.onclick = function() {
    if(myDiv.parentNode === parent1) {
        parent2.appendChild(myDiv);
    }else if(myDiv.parentNode === parent2){
        parent1.appendChild(myDiv);
    }
}
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dnbc/1/))